# Spring class path resource [applicationContext.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist

Tags: java, xml, spring

I'm placing `applicationContext.xml` in the same directory and package as my Java classes.

Doing the following to read it:

```
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
```

Yet I am consistently met with:

`IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException`

Which I do not get: The file is there, in the same directory as the classes. They're even compiled to `/out` and I can see it's all there.

I've tried putting it in `src/resources/applicationContext.xml` but to no avail.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Spring will look for it in the **root** of the classpath ...

- The "same directory and package as my Java classes" is not at the **root** of your classpath
- `src/resources` is not on your classpath at all

If you put it in `src/main/resources` then it will be (1) on your classpath and (2) in the **root** of your classpath.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem, as changing

```
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = 
    new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
```

to

```
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = 
    new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("packagename/applicationContext.xml");
```

My `XML` file also resides in the same package as my java classes exist.